# SVG AnimatMotion keyPoints substituted correctly in the browser's inspector but shown wrong on the path (chrome and Safari)

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks, cross-browser, svg-animate

I have been using animateMotion to animate an object along an SVG path, I am using the `keyPoints` to advance the animated object into the path using a variable, I am setting the variable using `useEffect()` function in react and it has been **working fine on FireFox** but not on **Chrome or Safari.**

```
 <path
                                    d={path}
                                    id="arc"
                                    className="a--path"
                                />
                                <foreignObject
                                    x={_get(translationValues, 'x')}
                                    y={_get(translationValues, 'y')}
                                    width="25"
                                    height="25"
                                    id="fo"
                                >
                                    <div id="note" className="note--t">
                                        <img
                                            src={noteImage}
                                            className="note--icon"
                                            alt="Notification Icon"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </foreignObject>
                                <animateMotion
                                    xlinkHref="#fo"
                                    begin="0s"
                                    dur="infinite"
                                    repeatCount="0"
                                    keyPoints={animationProgressValue}
                                    fill="freeze"
                                    keyTimes="0;1"
                                    calcMode="linear"
                                    path={path}
                                />
```

Setting the point, or how far along the path the object is is done using `keyPoints={AnimationProgressValue}` where `AnimationProgressValue` is `x+";0.5"` where x is [0.0, 1.0] and is set using `useEffect()` and the `";0.5"` part is always constant.

```
const [animationProgressValue, setAnimationProgressValue] = useState('0.0;0.5');

useEffect(() => {
    {
        if (Number(r > 0)) {
            setAnimationProgressValue(getAnimationProgressValue(r));
        }
    }
}, [r]);
```

The mystery part is that when things are loaded up in the browser, the `keyPoints` is showing correct value :

[image]

but showing the animated object at position 0.0 (which is the default initially set value and also the default value returned from `getAnimationProgressValue()`. )

I am almost convinced that it has to do with Async function (useEffect) being raced somehow and `animationProgressValue` being set late maybe? I have confirmed that it has to do with `animationProgressValue` and `useeffect()` by replacing `animationProgressValue` with a constant variable.

e.g:

```
const temp = '0.8;0.5'
```

and it does indeed show it at the right position (0.8) when using a constant temp var.

But then why the value is correctly displayed as `0.8` at the inspector (shown in screenshot), but showing it at position 0 on the path, and also why is it **working correctly on FireFox** if there is question of `r` or `useEffect()`.

Comment: I see attributes `begin="0s" dur="infinite"`, but no `end`. Is the animation actually running at some point? If not, the animation should have no effect on the position of the parent element.

Comment: @ccprog there is actually an interesting behaviour after changing begin value, I've change it to a whole number between 1 and 9 and the result is that the object position is suddenly corrected (appearing at 0.8 like it supposed to) and this happens regardless what value I put for begin 1,2, 5 or 9 it simply makes the object appear correctly at 0.8. However on Safari although the same correction is applied (appear at 0.8) but the object is duplicated , one appear where it supposed to and the other just floats somewhere on the page, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Making your application behavior dependent on setting illegal values is certainly not a good idea. See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/implnote.html#ErrorProcessing) on what is supposed to happene if the document is in error.